# Jenkins Build and Test Environment for Altera

Tags: jenkins, intel-fpga

Is there anyone Integrated Jenkins jobs with Embedded environment to build and test Altera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used **Altera** tool's **nois2 command prompt** to execute Altera build and test.

We need to invoke nios prompt using Jenkins build step "Execute Windows Batch command".